# Php create proper String from array

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, trim

I am trying to create this string:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -draw "line 425,400 525,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 165,405 265,405" -draw "line 295,405 395,405" -draw "line 425,405 525,405"
```

from this array data (function):

```
protected function getTextItems()
{
    if($this->hasCh())
    {
        return [[
            'title' => 'test1',
            'position0' => ['x0' => '165', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '265', 'y1' => '400'],
            'position1' => ['x0' => '165', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '265', 'y1' => '405'],
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'test2',
            'position0' => ['x0' => '295', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '395', 'y1' => '400'],
            'position1' => ['x0' => '295', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '395', 'y1' => '405'],
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'test3',
            'position0' => ['x0' => '425', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '525', 'y1' => '400'],
            'position1' => ['x0' => '425', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '525', 'y1' => '405'],
        ]];
    }
}
```

So far I did this:

```
    $itemCounter = 0;
    $positionCounter = 0;
    $recItemData = $this->getTextItems();
    $rec = 'convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime';
    foreach ($recItemData as $recItemDataKey => $recItemDataValue)
    {
        $rec .= ' -draw "line ' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position0']['x0'] . ',' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position0']['x1'];
        $rec .= ' ' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position0']['y0'] . ',' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position0']['y1'] . '"';
        if($itemCounter % count($recItemData)-1 == 0)
        {
            $rec .= ' -stroke blue ';
        }
        $rec .= ' -draw "line ' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position1']['x0'] . ',' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position1']['x1'];
        $rec .= ' ' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position1']['y0'] . ',' . $recItemData[$itemCounter]['position1']['y1'] . '"';
        if($itemCounter < count($recItemData))
        {
            $itemCounter++;
        }
    }
```

The above created this string (command), which is not correct:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -draw "line 425,400 525,400" -draw "line 425,400 525,400"
```

What Am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is `getTextItems()` always going to return a static list of value like that? Will there ever be a `position2`, `position3`, etc...?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus there will not be a position2 nor position3 .... it always return values it has some elseif branches which I did not show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$command = 'convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5';

$position0 = '-stroke lime';
$position1 = '-stroke blue';

foreach($this->getTextItems() as $v)
{
    $position0.= ' -draw "line '.$v['position0']['x0'].','.$v['position0']['x1'].' '.$v['position0']['y0'].','.$v['position0']['y1'].'"';

    $position1.= ' -draw "line '.$v['position1']['x0'].','.$v['position1']['x1'].' '.$v['position1']['y0'].','.$v['position1']['y1'].'"';
}

$command.= ' '.$position0.' '.$position1;

echo $command;
```

Comment: I think this worked but you have to add "line after the -draw

Comment: @JohnDoe2 I see, I fixed it up

Answer (score 1):

learn how foreach works `$recItemDataValue` equals `$recItemDataValue` `$itemCounter` equals `$recItemDataKey`, rewrite it will result a more readable code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
/**

*/
function getTextItems()
{

        return [[
                    'title' => 'test1',
                    'position0' => ['x0' => '165', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '265', 'y1' => '400'],
                    'position1' => ['x0' => '165', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '265', 'y1' => '405'],
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'test2',
                    'position0' => ['x0' => '295', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '395', 'y1' => '400'],
                    'position1' => ['x0' => '295', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '395', 'y1' => '405'],
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'test3',
                    'position0' => ['x0' => '425', 'x1' => '400', 'y0' => '525', 'y1' => '400'],
                    'position1' => ['x0' => '425', 'x1' => '405', 'y0' => '525', 'y1' => '405'],
                ]];

}

$recItemData = getTextItems();
$rec = 'convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 ';
$size = count($recItemData)-1;
    $rec .= ' -stroke lime ';
foreach ($recItemData as $recItemDataKey => $recItemDataValue) {
    $rec .= ' -draw "line ' . $recItemDataValue['position0']['x0'] . ',' . $recItemDataValue['position0']['x1'];
    $rec .= ' ' . $recItemDataValue['position0']['y0'] . ',' . $recItemDataValue['position0']['y1'] . '"';
}
    $rec .= ' -stroke blue ';
foreach ($recItemData as $recItemDataKey => $recItemDataValue)
    {
    $rec .= ' -draw "line ' . $recItemDataValue['position1']['x0'] . ',' . $recItemDataValue['position1']['x1'];
    $rec .= ' ' . $recItemDataValue['position1']['y0'] . ',' . $recItemDataValue['position1']['y1'] . '"';
}

$desired = 'convert size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -draw "line 425,400 525,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 165,405 265,405" -draw "line 295,405 395,405" -draw "line 425,405 525,405"';
echo $desired,"\n";
echo $rec,"\n";
```

same 6 lines but order changed

Comment: thanks, but I do not get the desired string do you get the correct one?

Comment: it creates me this : `convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 165,405 265,405" -stroke lime -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 295,405 395,405" -stroke lime -draw "line 425,400 525,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 425,405 525,405"`

Comment: I picked MonkeyZeus's answer because I think the code is a little better nevertheless I gave you a "thumbs up", thanks for your help

Comment: @JohnDoe2 De gustibus non est disputandum.